# Scala `map` but exit early on `Failure`

Tags: scala

If I have a `Seq`, I can `map` over it.

```
val ss = Seq("1", "2", "3")
println(ss.map(s => s.toInt))  // List(1, 2, 3)
```

But sometimes, the function that you pass to `map` can fail.

```
val ss = Seq("1", "2", "c")
println(ss.map(s => try { Success(s.toInt) } catch { case e: Throwable  => Failure(e) }))  // List(Success(1), Success(2), Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c"))
```

This last one will return a `Seq[Try[Int]]`. What I really want though is a `Try[Seq[Int]]`, where if any one of the mapping is a `Failure`, it stops the iteration and returns the `Failure` instead. If there is no error, I want it to just return all the converted elements, unpacked from the `Try`.

What is the idiomatic Scala way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it's idiomatic, but I would do something like this:

```
import util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

def toInt(s: String) =
  // Correct usage would be Try(s.toInt)
  try {
    Success(s.toInt)
  } 
  catch { 
    case e: Throwable  => Failure(e)
  }

def convert[A](ss: Seq[String], f: String => Try[A]) = {
  ss.foldLeft(Try(ListBuffer[A]())) { 
    case (a, s) =>
      for {
        xs <- a
        x  <- f(s)
      }
      yield xs :+ x
  }.map(_.toSeq)
}

scala> convert(List("1", "2"), toInt)
scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2))

scala> convert(List("1", "c"), toInt)
scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c")
```

If you really want to exit early instead of skipping elements you can use good old recursion:

```
def convert[A](ss: Seq[String], f: String => Try[A]) = {

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(ss: Seq[String], acc: ListBuffer[A]): Try[Seq[A]] = {
    ss match {
      case h::t =>
        f(h) match {
          case Success(x) => loop(t, acc :+ x)
          case Failure(e) => Failure(e)
        }
      case Nil =>
        Success(acc.toSeq)

    }
  }

  loop(ss, ListBuffer[A]())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the only one who's actually trying to address the spirit of my question. I had also thought of using a `foldLeft`, but I was hoping that converting an iterable of tries to a try of iterables was a common pattern in functional programming.

Comment: It is a well-known pattern in FP, only `sequence` from Scalaz doesn't work with `Try`, for `Option` it would be `List(1.some, 2.some).sequence //> Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))`.

Answer (score 6):

You may be overthinking this. The anonymous function in your `map` is essentially the same as `Try.apply`. If you want to end up with `Try[Seq[Int]]` then you can wrap the `Seq` in `Try.apply` and `map` within:

```
scala> val ss = Try(Seq("1", "2", "c").map(_.toInt))
ss: scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c")
```

If any of the `toInt`s fails, it will throw an exception and stop executing, and become a `Failure`.

Comment: Ah that's cool, thank you. But what if instead of `_.toInt`, I was using a function that would return a `Try[B]` instead of actually throwing an exception? Would that work too? I'm new to Scala and I can't seem to find `apply` in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html) ^_^;

Comment: @math4tots Click the big "C" and "O" in the scaladoc to switch between class and companion object: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try$@apply[T](r:=>T):scala.util.Try[T]